# HttpWebResponse mishandles values of multiple Set-Cookie headers, meaning CookieContainer doesn't store all intended cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebresponse, cookiecontainer

My C# Windows Forms program needs to talk to servers that include multiple `Set-Cookie` headers in HTTP responses.

.NET's `HttpWebResponse` seems to concatenate the contents of multiple `Set-Cookie` headers into one value - leaving the final value invalid. This results in sent cookies not being stored properly when using an associated `CookieContainer`.

**Example**

`HttpWebRequest` initiates a request and server replies with...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
....
Set-Cookie: cookie1=123; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: cookie2=456; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/somepath; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT
....
```

...and `HttpWebResponse`'s header value (copied from VS Debugger) is:

```
Set-Cookie: cookie1=123; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT,cookie2=456; Domain=127.0.0.1; Path=/somepath; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT
```

`HttpWebResponse` only contains `cookie1` in `Cookies` property.

.NET Reflection on the original `HttpWebRequest`'s `CookieContainer` to get all cookies (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991071) also shows only `cookie1` is parsed into an object and `cookie2` is ignored.

Are there ways to get multiple `Set-Cookie` headers handled properly without resorting to (significantly) lower-level or more complicated alternatives to `HttpWebResponse`?

Comment: Hello there, have you solved it? Because I'm interested in this problem.

Comment: Technically, no. I found out that the problem was with the server, not the client. The server was a quick C# WinForms application which I wrote for testing purposes, and in that I was doing `ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie: ....");` multiple times. The server combined these into one `Set-Cookie` header. As the server was for quick testing purposes only, the bug in `HttpWebResponse` wasn't much of a problem for me in the long run, but unfortunately the problem isn't really solved.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any code samples you have problems with. However i had similar problems with *CookieContainer.SetCookies()* method. When i tried to set a nice CookieHeader:

```
u=21seag24.ctcggq.f54cfsvgqp; v=1466603692; auth=1; dfp_group=15
```

CookieContainer absorbed only 1st cookie and thats it. But i need them All.!

To deal with this problem i added extra method:

```
    public void FillCookieContainer(string cookieString, string url)
    {
        foreach (var cookieElement in cookieString.Split(';'))
        {
            CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(url), cookieElement.Trim());
        }
    }
```

Referring to [Microsoft documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/cookiecontainer.cs) CookieContainer have a specific method like **CookieCutter** and **CookieParser** class. In general it rejects all the cookies with wrong format (not RFC2109/RFC2965).