# Iterate through and pull data from .CookieCollection() in C# Web Api project

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm reposting this question with screenshots as might make my problem easier to understand.

I have a CookieContainer that is populated on a HttpWebRequest.  I'm trying to iterate through the values and sort of got close with the following line of code:

```
  var getvalue = myWebRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://mydummy.domain.com"));
```

However, out of the 4 potential values listed in the cookie collection, it always returns the last entry.

Does anyone know how I can get at the list so I an iterate through and cherry pick the value I'm after?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the last image I've got an entry at position 2 out of the possible 4 entries (shown at array position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nqTy.jpg)).  It's that value JSESSIONID that I'm trying to pull out.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found this article which had an example which did exactly what I was after:

[How can I get all Cookies of a CookieContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983166/how-can-i-get-all-cookies-of-a-cookiecontainer)

Example code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Cookie> GetAllCookies(this CookieContainer c)
{
Hashtable k = (Hashtable)c.GetType().GetField("m_domainTable", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(c);
foreach (DictionaryEntry element in k)
{
    SortedList l = (SortedList)element.Value.GetType().GetField("m_list", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(element.Value);
    foreach (var e in l)
    {
        var cl = (CookieCollection)((DictionaryEntry)e).Value;
        foreach (Cookie fc in cl)
        {
            yield return fc;
        }
    }
}
}
```