# Is there a way to clear a CookieContainer?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

I want to clear ALL the cookies received in a CookieContainer without the need to initialize a new CookieContainer, HttpClientHandler and HttpClient. Is there a way? I've checked [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) but it seems I can only use GetCookies(Uri) to get all the cookies associated with a particular Uri.

```
var cc = new CookieContainer();

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cc
    };

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: It appears you need to use reflection.  What is the issue with creating a new HttpClient? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983166/how-can-i-get-all-cookies-of-a-cookiecontainer

Comment: @dana: I just feel then it might be a waste of resources since I'm using multiple tasks.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry about creating a few more instances of a class if the alternative is to use reflection to break into private members.  This is especially true since you are already making network requests over HTTP.

Answer (score 6):

The only solution I know is to expire all cookies:

```
        cc.GetCookies(new Uri(...))
            .Cast<Cookie>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(c => c.Expired = true);
```