# How to acess cookies in cookiecontainer

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm having trouble recursing the PHPSSID value of the cookie container ... how can I do this?

[Debug Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzlUd.png)

Path to acess this value:

```
m_domainTable = Count = 1
   [".biz.nf"] = {System.Net.PathList}
      (new System.Collections.Hashtable.HashtableDebugView(client.CookieContainer.m_domainTable).Items[0]).Value
       m_list = Count = 1
           ["/"] = {System.Net.CookieCollection}
                m_list = Count = 2
                  [0] = {PHPSESSID=q40djhd9ldu7sh27561nvgia22}
```

Thanks

@EDIT

I just found the awnser here [How can I get all Cookies of a CookieContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983166/how-can-i-get-all-cookies-of-a-cookiecontainer)

```
var allCokies = cookieContainer.GetAllCookies();
var phpSsid = allCokies.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name.Contains("PHP")).Value
```