# How to add AntiForgeryToken Or __RequestVerificationToken in integration tests?

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing, httpclient, antiforgerytoken

I am writing a test script in **C#** using **NUnit framework** where i send a **httprequestmeassage** to a *uri* to **GET** the **__RequestVerificationToken** in response. I wanted to know, how can i add that **__RequestVerificationToken** in the **json** and send it with a **POST** request. **Do i need to deserialize the response and then add the __RequestVerificationToken or can i directly do it from the response object of HttpResponseMessage type?** *I am fairly new to C# and integration testing. i would really appreciate it if the answers would be simplified to the core.* **Thank You So Much!**
This is what i have come up with up until now:

```
[Test]
public void DoLogin()
        {
            string uri = "/account/login";
            AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                ServiceType= ServiceType
            };

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(Consts.APIBaseURL) };
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseResult = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = responseResult.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.ToString());


            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                authenticationRequest,
                Formatting.Indented,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            //response message
            Task < HttpResponseMessage > response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = response.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage);

            //response content data
            HttpContent httpContent = httpResponseMessage.Content;
            Task <string> contentData = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string data = contentData.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Content Data: \n" + data);

        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve Cookies from HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060353/how-to-retrieve-cookies-from-httpresponsemessage)

Comment: No. I don't think you understood my question correctly, i am trying to login into a Login method with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. For which i have to send a GET request which returns a HttpResponse that has the cookie header with key "_requestVerificationToken" and value. I need to store the key and value and send it with the POST request method or JSON <I'm not sure if it needs to be sent with JSON or with the headers> for the login to be successful.