# Login to Corporate Wiki with predefined credentials (Webrequest)

Tags: .net, authentication, cookies

**Landing Page Login Form => Web App Authentication**

In my landing page login controller, I'm using the [cookie aware webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740851/2455159) to log into my MVC app (in a separate controller, I also will write a redirect to the corporate wiki and predefined credentials) but I haven't determined how to redirect my user to the Index page of the app.

The cookie object is there from contents issued by the app, *how do I inform the browser of the cookie/s it should be using for the redirect?*

My guess was that it might have involved the [auth cookie problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738176/creating-a-subdomain-auth-cookie-then-redirecting-to-subdomain-loses-the-cookie/19372220?noredirect=1#comment59519365_19372220) of this SO question and I've corresponded with the author of the answer, and he seems to think my approach possible... but doesn't say how.

I realise there are also ARR and request verifications cookies to consider, I have access to both app and wiki server, so should be able to access/ control / modify those if needed.