# Download image from img src in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to download image from `<img src="...">`.
If the `src` contains the file name and extension, I can download image simply passing url to my program.

However, when the `src` does not contains file name and extension, like

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" src="https://secure.somewebsite.net/website/member.php/1/folders/get_attach?mail_id=11111&amp;attach_id=1">
```

it is possible to download the image from C# code?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to successfully download `file name and extension` that isn't working for something like `/get_attach?mail_id=11111&amp;attach_id=1` ?

Comment: @bdimag i am using `webClient.DownloadFile(uri, @"C:\Users\Dev2\Downloads\img.png");` to download. Downloading it self is working but when I open it, it says the file is corrupted.

Comment: Suggest changing the extension to .TXT (or even .HTML) and open -- you're likely getting a message from the web server saying you're not permitted to hotlink or download the file directly

Comment: The additional details you proved below should have been included with your question. The reason you are getting a corrupted image is that the server does not authorize your request. The first step to your solution would be to authorize your request and then to download the image. Follow this link to see how to create a correct request and then you can download your image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183703/using-webclient-or-webrequest-to-login-to-a-website-and-access-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete sample

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://somedomain/image.png",
    @"c:\temp\image.png");

    // You can also you the async call 
    client.DownloadFileAsync("http://somedomain/image.png",
    @"c:\temp\image.png");
}
```

Comment: after download, it says file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.... : (

Comment: Do you need to be logged in to download this file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible,

You can use these methods to download the image from c# :

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\img.png");
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\img.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, WebClient is obselete (-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0014)

use for exemple

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var streamGot = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://somedomain/image.png");
await using var fileStream = new FileStream("img.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
streamGot.CopyTo(fileStream);
```