# Web Crawler C# (Login Using WebRequset Object)

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am writing a Web Crawler in C#. There is this website which has two text-fields (Username & Password) and a Login button. Now I want to Submit data through my C# code using WebRequest or WebClient object, but after executing this line

```
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
        values.Add("userName", "abc");
        values.Add("pwd", "Potagold201");
byte[] result = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", values);
        string ResultAuthTicket = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

I get redirected to Login Page... 
In short I am unable to post Data on that page.

Comment: You are posting 'pwd', but your post says the field is called 'password'. Coincidence?

Comment: well obviously i have to use the "ID" of the respective textfield which is pwd.. :P

Comment: Perhaps you should make that clear then

Comment: my bad. sorry... but the problem still persisits !!!

Comment: You might want to took a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183703/using-webclient-or-webrequest-to-login-to-a-website-and-access-data

Comment: Did you compare your post with the actual post and requests using the browser network debugger tools? maybe you're loosing some other filed?

Comment: @xvan can u elaborate your thoughts, i didn't get it... did u mean to say the usage of FIDDLER ?

Comment: All browsers have an embedded debugger: ctrl+shift+q (firefox), F12 IE, ctrl + shift+ I (chrome). You can capture the network traffic on the network tab.