# C# loading html of a webpage currently on

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a small app that can log in automatically on a website, get certain texts on the website and return to user.

To show what I have, I did below to make it log in,

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = logger.Document as System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument;

        try
        {
            doc.GetElementById("loginUsername").SetAttribute("value", "myusername");
            doc.GetElementById("loginPassword").SetAttribute("value", "mypassword");
            doc.GetElementById("loginSubmit").InvokeMember("click");
```

And below to load html of the page

```
        WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        Stream response = myClient.OpenRead(webbrowser.Url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
        string src = reader.ReadToEnd(); // finally reading html and saving in variable
```

Now, it successfully loaded html but html of the page where it's not logged in. Is there a way to refer to current html somehow? Or another way to achieve my goals. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Webclient class so you can use sessions and cookies.

check this Q&A: [Using WebClient or WebRequest to login to a website and access data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183703/using-webclient-or-webrequest-to-login-to-a-website-and-access-data)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make REST API calls and send the data like username and password from your code itself?
Is there any Web API for the URL ? If yes , you can simply call the service and pass on the required parameters. The API shall return in JSON/XML which you can parse and extract information