# Using HttpWebRequest to login to a website

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

*I know there are many similar question here but I tried almost everything with no luck.*

Basically, I've never used the `POST` method before, and I'm struggling to login to *any* website and maintain the cookies in order to use in next requests.

Here's my code (I'm using Facebook for testing only):

**Login method:**

```
protected static CookieContainer Login()
{
    string userName = "username";
    string password = "password";

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "email=" + userName + "&pass=" + password;
    byte[] postDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");

    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";
    httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;
    httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }

    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            foreach (Cookie cookie in httpWebResponse.Cookies)
            {
                cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    return cookieContainer;
}
```

**Retrieve the homepage after logging in:**

```
void Retrieve()
{
    var req =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com");
    req.Proxy = null;
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";
    req.CookieContainer = Login();
    string src = "";
    using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        src = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
    txt.Text = src;
    wb.DocumentText = src;
}
```

I also tried to create the `CookieContainer` first and then assign it to both requests, but still no luck.
I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm missing.

Note: As mentioned, I'm using Facebook here just for testing. If required I can post the original website I'm trying to login to.

---

### Update:

The actual website I'm trying to automate the login process for is: [carrierpoint.com](https://market-atl.carrierpoint.com/core/jsp/CPLogin.jsp).

I have to say I don't really have much experience with web requests/responses, authentication, etc. I never worked with ASP.NET or any kind of web application, so please excuse my limited knowledge in this area.

So for more info, this is an example of request & response headers for a successful login to this website:

[image: Request & response headers for a successful login]

If this isn't just about cookies, I would appreciate if someone can help me figure out what other elements would be needed to submit the correct request and maintain the logged in session.

Also would be great if anyone can suggest some resources as a good start for me to generally understand the correct way(s) to use the `POST` method and website login & authentication (I mean the general concept to be able to use on other websites).

Comment: Your code does not check if the initial login to Facebook was successful.

Comment: @Dai, thank you for your reply. How do I do that? I believe it's unsuccessful. 1) The response of the second request is the fb home page *not logged in*. 2) I tried to check on `cookieContainer.Count` and it's always zero. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe there is more to logging into facebook than just cookies. What is the website you're trying to login to and what kind of authorization are they looking for? Is it Basic Authentication, OAuth? What kind of request? Is it an API endpoint? There needs to be a lot more information than this.

Comment: @trevster344 I just edited the question. Please have a look on my update.

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate with oAuth2 -- then your auth flow will need to be a two way street.  You will need to make a request to the Authentication Provider and then provide them a URL that they can post a request to once the user has authenticated themselves -- at that point I believe the cookie is present.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any immediately differing methods to the way you're doing it. The login isn't quite so straight forward for us though because we don't have credentials to do the proper testing and quite honestly we can't simply brute force this. I would note two things though:

You're encoding as ASCII. You should encode your data as UTF8.

`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.

You need to url encode your data.

`postdata = "loginId=" & WebUtility.UrlEncode("myloginid") & "&password=" & WebUtility.UrlEncode("mypassword")`

You may need to `Import System.Web`.

I would honestly verify Carrierpoint doesn't have some kind of developers API for you. A lot of big businesses have some sort of API they were forced to develop for their operations.

You don't really need to learn `HttpWebRequest` but for practice I would try using PayPal or Stripe's API's. They're both REST API's for doing CRUD operations with respective accounts in the world of online payments. They're very easy to use and they both use forms of OAuth authentication, and Basic Authentication.

In the case of PayPal you would send a basic authorization request to retrieve an OAuth token:

```
Dim _req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(Base_URL & "/api/v1/token")
_req.Method = "POST"
_req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ClientID & ":" & SecretKey))) 'Convert both credentials into a base 64 string
_req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested 'Sends authorization header immediately on first request
```

In these scenarios you'll see response strings that are often times in `JSON` format:

```
{
"scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
"access_token": "EEwJ6tF9x5WCIZDYzyZGaz6Khbw7raYRIBV_WxVvgmsG",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"app_id": "APP-6XR95014BA15863X",
"expires_in": 28800
}
```

After you got your token by parsing that JSON response you would then send it with any request you needed to make to the api. In the example of using PayPal's Payments API for retrieving all payments in a list

```
Dim _req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(Base_URL & "/v1/payments/payment")
_req.Method = Method.ToUpper
_req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & Token) 'The access_token from the previous authentication request
_req.Headers.Add("Accept_Language", "en_US")
_req.Accept = "application/json"
```

Retrieving responses is always the same as you have done. The only thing you will have to do is parse the data and make sure you know what format the data is in. If you need to parse `JSON` then use the `Newtonsoft` NugetPackage. It's very easy to us as well and has a load of documentation. RestSharp is another Nuget Package which contains dozens of helper methods to perform RESTful requests for cases like PayPal and Stripe.

Resources:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

https://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html

If you need anymore help do not be afraid to ask.

Comment: Yes I'd suggest using RestSharp, makes Cookies much easier.  https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I don't have access credentials to this specific website anymore. I'll give your suggestions a try (specially RestSharp) with other websites and see how it goes.

Comment: Everyone does things differently so you'll always have to learn but the basics will get easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should set cookie container for login request. Besides, the code handling the response can be simplified, so the remainder of `Login` methods looks like:

```
...
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    cookieContainer.Add(httpWebResponse.Cookies);
    return cookieContainer;
}
```

Comment: Okay, now the `Response.Cookies.Count > 0` but still the webpage returned in the second response isn't logged in.

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebRequest is tricky, and not well suited for web IMO.. You may want to write your helpers, or use nugets.

I can succesfully authenticate to facebook with the code bellow (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184097/7875425))

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Main logic: Login && GetHomePage
        var client = new FacebookClient();
        if (client.Login("userMail", "userPassword"))
            client.GetHomePage();
    }
}

// Specific client
public class FacebookClient : CookieAwareWebClient
{
    public bool Login(string email, string password)
    {
        var loginResult = this.Login("https://www.facebook.com/login.php",
        new NameValueCollection
        {
          { "email", email },
          { "pass", password }
        });

        return loginResult;
    }

    public void GetHomePage()
    {
        // Here's the magic.. Cookies are injected via an overriden
        var webRequest = this.GetWebRequest(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com"));

        string src = "";
        using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            src = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code from linked post, i just added UserAgent string..

```
// General client
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
      : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer container)
    {
        CookieContainer = container;
    }


    public bool Login(string loginPageAddress, NameValueCollection loginData)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";

        var parameters = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in loginData.Keys)
        {
            parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(loginData[key]));
        }
        parameters.Length -= 1;

        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters.ToString());
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();

        CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;                
    }

    // Add cookies to WebRequest
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very weird! I'm not sure how you *successfully* managed to login using this code while the buffer written by the `RequestStream` is always incorrect. `loginData.ToString()` will always return `"System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"`!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. a) I'm not sure whether the username & password should be `UrlEncode`d or not? b) I can't really see how this implementation is any different than my code in the question. AFAICT, it just uses `WebClient` -*which is built on top of `HttpWebRequest`*- instead of `HttpWebRequest`, but the code logic is still the same (please correct me if I'm mistaken). However, I just tested it anyway, and the returned webpage is still not logged in.