# Can't use LINQ on CookieCollection despite the enumerator being accessible

Tags: c#, linq

Following roughly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074200/1525840), I want to get the first cookie with a certain name given an URI.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
...
CookieCollection cookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri);
```

Then, I can access the first (and at the moment the only) cookie like this.

```
Cookie cookie = cookies[0];
```

I see it's a collection and it has an enumerator. However, when I try to use LINQ, it seems that the collection isn't getting anything like this.

```
Cookie cookie = cookies
  .First(c => c.Name == "vanilla");
```

The LINQ is imported at the top and it definitely works with a few test lines I threw in. There's no `AsList()` or `ToArray()` according to the intellisense, neither. The collection seems not to be very collection'ish.

What am I missing?

**edit**

I ended up copying over the contents like this. But it seems to clunky...

```
Cookie[] cookies = new Cookie[cookieJar.Count];
cookieJar.GetCookies(uri).CopyTo(cookies, 0);
Cookie cookie = cookies
  .First(c => c.Name == "pm_retention_urls");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CookieCollection` only implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<Cookie>`. You can create an `IEnumerable<Cookie>` using `Cast`:

```
Cookie cookie = cookies.Cast<Cookie>().First(c => c.Name == "vanilla");
```

Comment: Are you saying that `IEnumerable` isn't LINQ'able and that it's generic counterpart `IEnumerable<Something>` is? I haven't noticed that ever (doing LINQ since 2007 I somehow failed to use it on untyped version).

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Yes, almost all LINQ methods are on `IEnumerable<T>` not `IEnumerable`, the only `IEnumerable` methods are `Cast` and `OfType` which are used to create generic sequences from non-generic ones.

Comment: Well, what do you know? 12 years later and I still learn new, basic stuff. Not sure if amazed or embarrassed...   :)